# Initial FormData post fails

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am trying to asynchronously post a form containing an image using FormData in javascript.  I am using [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) as reference; specifically the part under: [**Handling the upload process for a file, asynchronously**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Handling_the_upload_process_for_a_file.2C_asynchronously).

Instead of drag and drop, I am trying to use a button like a normal form submission.  The problem that I am seeing is that upon first submission, I don't hit the server; and there is no meaningful message showing up in firebug.  If I try to use the same picture, or just resubmit right away, I then hit the server successfully.  The moment I change pictures again, it fails to hit the server.

Here is my html / javascript.

```
<form action="#">
    <input id="image-one-upload" type="file" name="Image" />
    <img id="img-one-prev" class="preview" src="#" />
    <label for="image-one-caption">Caption</label>
    <input id="image-one-caption" type="text" name="Caption" />

    <button id="upload-btn">Save</button>
</form>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function sendFile(file) {
            var uri = "SaveImage";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData();

            xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    // Handle response.
                    alert(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
                }
            };
            fd.append('Image', file);
            fd.append('Caption', "caption"); // testing post of additional form data
            // Initiate a multipart/form-data upload
            xhr.send(fd);
        };

        $(document).on('change', "#image-one-upload", function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $("#img-one-prev").attr('src', e.target.result);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', "#upload-btn", function () {
            sendFile($("#image-one-upload")[0].files[0]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**More Information**

Below are some screenshots of the first failed post, and then the second successful post.  It looks like it's something to do with the headers, I just don't know what or why it's happening.

Bad Post
[image: Bad Post]

Good Post
[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: I fixed the problem by moving the button outside of the form.  I don't know why that worked, so an answer would still be appreciated.

Comment: Try preventing the default action of the button click, which is to submit the form. `button`'s `type` attribute by default is `submit`. Also I'd recommend listening to the `submit` event instead.